# Issues when reading a .nc file

Tags: matlab

I got this `.nc` file. However, when I read the file like this

```
ncid = netcdf.open(ncfile)
```

It gives me only a number. It was supposed to contain some data. I am not sure what's wrong with it. 
Can anyone please provide some information?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/netcdf.open.html), `netcdf.open` only returns the NetCDF ID, not the data:

> `ncid = netcdf.open(source)` opens `source`, which can be the name of a
>   NetCDF file or the URL of an OPeNDAP NetCDF data source, for read-only
>   access. Returns a NetCDF ID in `ncid`.

You probably want to use [`ncread`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ncread.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

> ncid = netcdf.open(ncfile)
>   Where ncid is a netCDF file identifier returned by netcdf.create or
>   netcdf.open.

**Eg : In your Case**

```
 ncid=netcdf.open(ncfile,'NC_NOWRITE'); 
 varidp=netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'varname'); //returns varid
```

**Eg : Official**

This example opens the example netCDF file included with MATLAB®, example.nc, and uses several inquiry functions to get the ID of the first variable.

```
ncid = netcdf.open('example.nc','NC_NOWRITE');

% Get information about first variable in the file.
[varname, xtype, dimids, atts] = netcdf.inqVar(ncid,0);

% Get variable ID of the first variable, given its name
varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,varname)
```

Ref:http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/netcdf.inqvarid.html

Thanks